# Variant Type Structure (oaidl.h) in c++ for Mac OSX?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, variant, safearray

I'm trying to port my c++ dll developped in windows which make extensive use of Variant (ole/com) type Structure (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) . This type is defined in the oaidl.h file of visual studio and is imported in windows with "windows.h".

Is there any existing way to use this type in c++ in xcode? Obvioulsy to include windows.h make no sense and doesn't work. Do you know a library to use this type on OSX ? Note that variant use the safearray structure which i don't find on mac neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a short answer: no.
VARIANT includes many types and interfaces which only make sense in a Windows enviroment (e.g. IUnkown). I myself changed from Windows Development to POSIX C++ OSX and Linux. As I also transfer code from windows to the standard unix world.

The way with the smallest impact IMHO is to replace VARIANT with an own type e.g. MYVARIANT and only move the part of the union wich you really need. This gives you the freedom to make a typedef which switch between Microsoft and the rest of the world.

But in my personal opinion you should try to get rid of it. Try to encapsulate it in a class at least. COM (which is the best example of a good idea getting to a hell for developers) and its VARIANT system is the last thing I am missing on any other system.

**UPDATE**
As I searched a little deeper, I found that boost has a variant system here:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/variant.html

Answer (score 1):

You can see what I have tried to do here :

[BSTR's and VARIANT's under... mac os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940136/bstrs-and-variants-under-mac-os-x)

where I described how I am now trying to port a `VARIANT`to mac os x, if it can help.