# BSTR's and VARIANT's under... mac os x

Tags: c++, excel, vba, macos, bstr

Under mac os x I have office 2011 and its excel and VBA, and I have gcc-5.3.0's g++.

I played a lot to passing arrays (of numerical built-in types) from VBA to the dylib (extension of dll's on mac os x) and updating them and sending them back to VBA, see for instance :

[passing c/c++ dylib function taking pointer to VBA on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237575/passing-c-c-dylib-function-taking-pointer-to-vba-on-mac)

Now, I would like to do the same with strings, and first with just one string, not an array. I want to receive the string from VBA, modify it in C++, and send it back, updated, to VBA.

The code on the `C++` side is :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h> //for toupper

extern "C"
{
      void toupperfunc(char *vbstr)
      {
          size_t i = 0U;
          char c;
          do {
              c = vbstr[i];
              vbstr[i]=toupper(c);
              ++i;
          } while(vbstr[i]!=0);
      }
}
```

in the file `thedylib.dylib`, compiled as follows (office 2011 for mac os x is 32 bits) :

```
g++ -m32 -Wall -g -c ./thedylib.cpp
g++ -m32 -dynamiclib ./thedylib.o -o ./thedylib.dylib
```

whereas on the VBA side (in excel 2011 for mac os x) I have this code :

```
Declare Sub toupperfunc Lib "/path/to/the/dylib/thedylib.dylib" (ByVal str As String)

Public Sub DoIt()
    Dim str As String
    str = "Ludwig von Mises"
    Call toupperfunc(str)
    MsgBox (str)
End Sub
```

and executing it pop's out "LUDWIG VON MISES" as expected.

*Remark 1.* Note the `ByVal` in front of the string in the sub's signature. Putting a `ByRef` instead would have produced a crash at runtime. Even more strange : imagine I add a `tolowerfunc` in my dylib (same code as for `toupperfunc` but relying on `ctype.h`'s `tolower` C++ function). It also works as expected, but this time, putting a `ByRef` in front of the string in the signature instead of a `ByVal` doesn't provoke a runtime crash anymore. So, is there something different between C++ functions `toupper` and `tolower` ? If so, what ? **What's does explain this behaviour ?**

*Remark 2.* As a corollary of the fact that what I described above works, we know now that Excel 2011 VBA on a mac os x does not exchange strings with a dylib using the same in-memory format that a COM BSTR uses. It uses null-terminated `char*` strings instead.

Taking into account remark 2 and as "using VARIANT under os x" was my long-term goal, see for instance :

[Passing a VARIANT from mac OS X Excel 2011 VBA to c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32301783/passing-a-variant-from-mac-os-x-excel-2011-vba-to-c),

I finally mimicked a `VARIANT` structure in a `VARIANT.h` file as you can see in the following code :

```
#ifndef VARIANT_H
#define VARIANT_H

#include <inttypes.h> // needed for gcc analogues of __int64 and unsigned __int64

typedef unsigned short VARTYPE;
typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
// typedef __int64 LONGLONG;
typedef int64_t LONGLONG;
// typedef unsigned __int64 ULONGLONG;
typedef uint64_t ULONGLONG;
typedef long LONG;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef short SHORT;
typedef float FLOAT;
typedef double DOUBLE;
/* 0 == FALSE, -1 == TRUE */
typedef short VARIANT_BOOL;
/* For backward compatibility */
typedef bool _VARIANT_BOOL;
typedef LONG SCODE;
typedef unsigned long ULONG;
typedef unsigned short USHORT;
typedef unsigned long ULONG;
typedef char CHAR;
typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef int INT;
typedef unsigned int UINT;
typedef unsigned int * PUINT;
typedef union tagCY
{
        struct _tagCY
        {
                ULONG Lo;
                LONG Hi;
        } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
        LONGLONG int64;
} CY;

typedef double DATE;

/*#ifndef _MAC*/
//typedef wchar_t WCHAR;    // wc,   16-bit UNICODE character
typedef char WCHAR;
/*#else
   // some Macintosh compilers don't define wchar_t in a convenient location, or define it as a char
   typedef unsigned short WCHAR;    // wc,   16-bit UNICODE character
 #endif*/

typedef WCHAR OLECHAR;
typedef OLECHAR * BSTR;
typedef BSTR * LPBSTR;
typedef void * PVOID;
/*// #define POINTER_64 __ptr64
 #define POINTER_64 unsigned long long*/

//typedef void *POINTER_64 PVOID64;
typedef struct tagSAFEARRAYBOUND
{
        ULONG cElements;
        LONG lLbound;
}       SAFEARRAYBOUND;

typedef struct tagSAFEARRAYBOUND * LPSAFEARRAYBOUND;

typedef struct tagSAFEARRAY
{
        USHORT cDims;
        USHORT fFeatures;
        ULONG cbElements;
        ULONG cLocks;
        PVOID pvData;
        SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound[1];
}       SAFEARRAY;

typedef SAFEARRAY * LPSAFEARRAY;

typedef struct tagDEC
{
        USHORT wReserved;
        union
        {
                struct
                {
                        BYTE scale;
                        BYTE sign;
                } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
                USHORT signscale;
        } DUMMYUNIONNAME1;
        ULONG Hi32;
        union
        {
                struct
                {
                        ULONG Lo32;
                        ULONG Mid32;
                } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
                ULONGLONG Lo64;
        } DUMMYUNIONNAME2;
} DECIMAL;

/*#define __tagVARIANT
   #define __VARIANT_NAME_1
   #define __VARIANT_NAME_2
   #define __VARIANT_NAME_3
   #define __tagBRECORD
 #define __VARIANT_NAME_4*/

typedef /* [wire_marshal] */ struct tagVARIANT VARIANT;

struct tagVARIANT
{
        union
        {
                struct __tagVARIANT
                {
                        VARTYPE vt;
                        WORD wReserved1;
                        WORD wReserved2;
                        WORD wReserved3;
                        union
                        {
                                // non ptr stuff
                                LONGLONG llVal;
                                LONG lVal;
                                BYTE bVal;
                                SHORT iVal;
                                FLOAT fltVal;
                                DOUBLE dblVal;
                                VARIANT_BOOL boolVal;
                                // _VARIANT_BOOL bool;
                                SCODE scode;
                                CY cyVal;
                                DATE date;
                                BSTR bstrVal;
                                // ptr stuff
                                /*IUnknown*/ void *punkVal;
                                /*IDispatch*/ void *pdispVal;
                                SAFEARRAY * parray;
                                BYTE * pbVal;
                                SHORT * piVal;
                                LONG * plVal;
                                LONGLONG * pllVal;
                                FLOAT * pfltVal;
                                DOUBLE * pdblVal;
                                VARIANT_BOOL * pboolVal;
                                _VARIANT_BOOL * pbool;
                                SCODE * pscode;
                                CY * pcyVal;
                                DATE * pdate;
                                BSTR * pbstrVal;
                                /*IUnknown*/ void ** ppunkVal;
                                /*IDispatch*/ void ** ppdispVal;
                                SAFEARRAY ** pparray;
                                VARIANT * pvarVal;
                                PVOID byref;
                                CHAR cVal;
                                USHORT uiVal;
                                ULONG ulVal;
                                ULONGLONG ullVal;
                                INT intVal;
                                UINT uintVal;
                                DECIMAL * pdecVal;
                                CHAR * pcVal;
                                USHORT * puiVal;
                                ULONG * pulVal;
                                ULONGLONG * pullVal;
                                INT * pintVal;
                                UINT * puintVal;
                                struct __tagBRECORD
                                {
                                        PVOID pvRecord;
                                        /*IRecordInfo*/ void * pRecInfo;
                                } VARIANT_NAME_4;
                        }  VARIANT_NAME_3;
                } VARIANT_NAME_2;
                DECIMAL decVal;
        } VARIANT_NAME_1;
};

typedef VARIANT * LPVARIANT;

typedef VARIANT VARIANTARG;

typedef VARIANT * LPVARIANTARG;





#endif
```

I stick to what's done on the windows side for everything except for `BSTR` for which I set :

```
typedef char WCHAR;
typedef WCHAR OLECHAR;
typedef OLECHAR * BSTR;
```

(I also cut out pure COM stuff, namely portions of code concerning `IUnknown` and `IDispatch`.)

Having defined this "light" `VARIANT` structure, I want to play the same game as for arrays of `double`'s and for `string`'s, that is, exchange `VARIANT`'s between VBA and a C++ dynamic library. So I designed this C++ code :

```
#include "/path/to/VARIANT.h"
#include <ctype.h>

VARTYPE getvt(const VARIANT & var_in)
{
    return var_in.VARIANT_NAME_1.VARIANT_NAME_2.vt;
}

extern "C"
{
      void updatevar(VARIANT * var_in_out, bool converttoupper)
      {
          VARTYPE vt = getvt(*var_in_out);
          switch (vt)
          {
              case 3:
              {
                  long l = (*var_in_out).VARIANT_NAME_1.VARIANT_NAME_2.VARIANT_NAME_3.lVal;
                  l *= 2L;
                  (*var_in_out).VARIANT_NAME_1.VARIANT_NAME_2.VARIANT_NAME_3.lVal = l;
              }
              break;
              case 8024:
              {

              }
              break;
              case 8:
              {
                  BSTR wc = (*var_in_out).VARIANT_NAME_1.VARIANT_NAME_2.VARIANT_NAME_3.bstrVal ;
                  int i = 0;
                  do
                  {
                      char c = wc[i];
                      wc[i]= converttoupper ? static_cast<char>(toupper(c)) : static_cast<char>(tolower(c));
                      ++i;
                  } while(wc[i]!=0);
                  (*var_in_out).VARIANT_NAME_1.VARIANT_NAME_2.VARIANT_NAME_3.bstrVal = &wc[0];
              }
              break;
              default:
              {
                  return;
              }
          }
      }
}
```

put in `thevarianttest.cpp`, compiled as follows :

```
g++ -m32 -Wall -g -c ./thevarianttest.cpp
g++ -m32 -dynamiclib ./thevarianttest.o -o ./thevarianttest.dylib
```

and used in the VBA side (in excel 2011 for mac os x) as follows :

```
Declare Sub updatevar Lib "/path/to/the/dylib/thevarianttest.dylib" (ByRef x As Variant, ByVal istoupper As Boolean)

Public Sub doit()
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim l As Long
    l = -666
    x = l
    Call updatevar(x, True)
    MsgBox (x)
    Dim s as String
    s = "Ludwig von Mises"
    x = s
    Call updatevar(x, False)
    MsgBox (x)
    s = "Ludwig von Mises"
    x = s
    Call updatevar(x, True)
    MsgBox (x) 'FAILURE...
End Sub
```

Executing this VBA code now successively pops out :
   -1332
   ludwig von mises
   Ludwig von Mises

the first two are ok, but for the last, "LUDWIG VON MISES" was expected... And the last one relies ultimately on C++'s `toupper` function, the same function from previous remark 1 that wasn't allowing me a `ByRef` use in the VBA in the first example...

**So what's going on ? Why was it working in the first example and not anymore in this second ?**

*Remark 3.* Note the `ByRef` in front of the `VARIANT` the signature of the sub. Putting a `ByVal` instead provokes a runtime crash... (It's the opposite to what was happening with strings and without variants, in the first VBA code.)

Comment: I do not know yet whether my comment is related to your problem, because analysis takes time, and I do not know whether someone is still interested on the answer...

**However, did you realise that the amount of characters is stored in the a higher address and the string content in the other direction?**

If not, and **someone still interrested** then may take a closer look to help.

As far as  I remember the pointer points dirctly to Data string. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr

Comment: Just anoother comment to understand the memory layout: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/726867/Tracking-BSTR-Memory-Allocations-to-Find-Memory-Le

Comment: @Jörg'Wuwei'Brüggmann Yes, I did realize it ... Thanks for the link

Comment: Was that the problem, @Olorin?

Comment: Sadly no ... I finally definitely forgot the idea of working seriously on a mac ...

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @Olorin 's initial attempt, I built a C++ library that allows to share strings and arrays between VBA and C++ using the variant data type as a wrapper. I also added extra functionality such as type safety for arrays, move semantics, etc. Here's the repo in case anyone's still interested:

https://github.com/buenop/MinXL